# How can I create Validate phone number in woocommerce checkout page that starts from "05"

Tags: validation, woocommerce, numbers, hook, checkout

How can I create Validate phone number in woocommerce checkout page that starts from "05". And Should be 10 digit number in max. But, Space should not be contained in that 10 digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the answer and it's working:

```
// Limit Woocommerce phone field to 10 digits number || Mdsourov || sourov.com
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'njengah_custom_checkout_field_process');

  function njengah_custom_checkout_field_process() {

    global $woocommerce;

      // Check if set, if its not set add an error. This one is only requite for companies

 $is_correct = preg_match('/^05[0-9]{8}$/', $_POST['billing_phone']);
            if ( $_POST['billing_phone'] && !$is_correct) {

        wc_add_notice( "Incorrect Phone Number! Please enter valid 10 digits phone number that start with 05"  ,'error' );
    }
}
```